# Sort by price and remove prices

Tags: python, sorting

I have a shopping list:

```
items = [
    ['Aspirin', 'Walgreens', 6.00],
    ['book lamp', 'Amazon', 2.87],
    ['popsicles', 'Walmart', 5.64],
    ['hair brush', 'Amazon', 6.58],
    ['Listerine', 'Walmart', 3.95],
    ['gift bag', 'Target', 1.50]
]
```

I want to sort the items from cheapest to highest price, and remove the prices. (I don't need them anymore then, I'll just buy from top down until I run out of money). Goal is:

```
items = [
    ['gift bag', 'Target'],
    ['book lamp', 'Amazon'],
    ['Listerine', 'Walmart'],
    ['popsicles', 'Walmart'],
    ['Aspirin', 'Walgreens'],
    ['hair brush', 'Amazon']
]
```

A way that works but looks clumsy ([demo/template](https://tio.run/##fZE9b4MwEIZ3/4rrBEiRlZKSppEYoq4dK3VADE56gBWwT2dXavrnqaEENVKEp/t4fH7fM118Y81mR9xrj52DHAoB4RTRwZFmbaIVRB@qrRnRuJBs5XpdribmaO0ZWtXRQB069WMHPpW75xkhS06fWnTToE6xD2Emt08z0yjNcOQv19zM2cpsNzNv2nkMevB2zka@ZDNT68rDUdUD8q64xoF4lNm6FKUQ@E148v8c3sEXnS1rWXY8d@@udXkTQX2vO7LswRKy8pbF9bdcqOJnPKYrOOMlvyJyqAVPQWmcJomoLIMGbYCVqTFu0fzdSpL9@PiYFLoMQ69hsU/LvmLbAVHQ7GFSQSQE0XRdjK04erXMYb8PEegKJnk5TEvH1mEwzNbUUdL/Ag)):

```
import operator
items = sorted(items, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
for i in range(len(items)):
    items[i] = items[i][:2]
```

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: @closer Bah, I wish you had more faith in me :-). There's a neat and educational solution that I'd like people to find and see. It's not on SO, I checked the database. Even Google finds only one case.

Comment: Can you clarify the "buy until I run out of money" part, please? The code you've provided makes no comparison to a total price.

Comment: @gvee That's just the reason for why I don't need the prices anymore. Not part of the task.

Comment: By creating a new object a naively `map(operator.itemgetter(0, 1), sorted(...))`

Comment: there is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Juraj I know. But this isn't.

Comment: If anyone wonders about that one previous case [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+%22key%3Dlist.pop%22) found: it was in [2007-April.txt - Python mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-April.txt).

Comment: Oops, actually I overlooked one there, and it *is* [on Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222973/110278), haha @Juraj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how I really feel about using `key` for side-effects, but:

```
items.sort(key=list.pop)
print(items)
```

Result:

```
[['gift bag', 'Target'], ['book lamp', 'Amazon'], ['Listerine', 'Walmart'], ['popsicles', 'Walmart'], ['Aspirin', 'Walgreens'], ['hair brush', 'Amazon']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the beauty of list comprehension in python.

```
items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2])
items = [x[:2] for x in items]
```

Comment: Or in one line `items = [x[:2] for x in sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2])]`

Answer (score 2):

What if you use the in built `sorted` method:

```
items = [
    ['Aspirin', 'Walgreens', 6.00],
    ['book lamp', 'Amazon', 2.87],
    ['popsicles', 'Walmart', 5.64],
    ['hair brush', 'Amazon', 6.58],
    ['Listerine', 'Walmart', 3.95],
    ['gift bag', 'Target', 1.50]
]
# this sorts by the third element from your each list
new_list = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2]) 
    
for i in new_list:
    del i[2]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggested I could use more 'for' and fewer builtins:

```py
_,items = zip(*sorted((z, x) for *x,z in items))
```

Comment: Nah, no `for` intended. I was just joking regarding your first code here and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385452/how-would-i-get-a-list-of-pairs-where-every-element-from-list1-is-paired-with-so/75395480#comment133025713_75385676).

Comment: This is nice, but the intended solution is half as long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```py
items = list(map(lambda x: x[:2], sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[2])))
print(items)
```

You can also try [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
import operator
items = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0, 1), sorted(items, key=operator.itemgetter(2))))
```

---

```
[['gift bag', 'Target'], ['book lamp', 'Amazon'], ['Listerine', 'Walmart'], ['popsicles', 'Walmart'], ['Aspirin', 'Walgreens'], ['hair brush', 'Amazon']]
```

Comment: What about this?

Comment: Well, I dislike list(map(lambda, but I'm upvoting everything better than what I showed, and this still qualifies :-)

Answer (score 1):

zipzipzip

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice

print(
    list(zip(*islice(zip(*sorted(items, key=itemgetter(-1))),2)))
)
# [('gift bag', 'Target'), ('book lamp', 'Amazon'), ('Listerine', 'Walmart'), ('popsicles', 'Walmart'), ('Aspirin', 'Walgreens'), ('hair brush', 'Amazon')]
```

Comment: Just plugging builtins together without looping yourself? Who does that? :-)

Comment: But if that's your guess at what I meant: No, there's something **much** better.

Comment: @KellyBundy Not really a guess, because `zip(*islice(zip(*...), 2))` doesn't seem much better than `map(itemgetter(0,1), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

The inevitable `numpy` version. Select the first two columns by infering a reordering wrt to the values of the last columns.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(items)

a = a[:,:2][a[:,-1].argsort()]
```

Comment: You can shorten that.

Comment: Advice: slice thrice ≠ nice. Slice twice suffice.

Comment: (Not sure it's called slicing, might be indexing, but I only realized afterwards.)

Comment: What I (probably) meant: `a = a[a[:,-1].argsort(),:2]`